Why does Python3 crash when attempting to run it on macOS Sequoia 15.1.1?
On an M1 Max Mac Studio (currently using macOS Sequoia 15.1.1), I can't seem to run Python the most direct way:
shunter@Mac-Studio-3 ~ % which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
shunter@Mac-Studio-3 ~ % python3
zsh: killed     python3
shunter@Mac-Studio-3 ~ % 

But
shunter@Mac-Studio-3 ~ % /usr/bin/python3        
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct  4 2024, 08:01:31) 
[Clang 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

How should I go about getting the local Python to work?

Where did the one in /usr/local/bin come from?  Homebrew?  The one in /usr/bin is from the Apple Command Line Tools.

I don't know, but I do know that /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

Sometime in the past you installed a third-party Python interpreter (probably from python.org) which is now obsolete and doesn't work. You should either update it, or else remove it and use the system Python binary in /usr/bin. Note that the system Python is also outdated and doesn't come with all the usual add-ons. There is also a Python interpreter in Xcode, if you have it installed.
To remove the non-functional interpreter, delete the symbolic link at /usr/local/bin/python3 and also delete /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework. These are not part of either Sequoia or Xcode.
In case anyone is confused, the system Python and Xcode Python are not the same. They are the same version if you have the current versions of macOS and Xcode, but the binaries are different. Furthermore, the directory /usr/bin is on the read-only System volume and can't be changed by anything except the macOS Installer. Xcode installs only on the Data volume.

The system python /usr/bin/python3 IS the version that comes with Xcode, and is version 3.9.6. If you don't already have Xcode, you are prompted to install the Xcode CLI tools to get it to run. Not up-to-date, but hardly outdated.

I think the actual file in /usr/bin/python3 is nopt actually python but code that looks for the Xcode python and then retuirns that or if it can't find Xcode then tells you to install it. In this way the code does not change when Xcode does.
